# Is there a way in python to verify with is_text_present() method that certain regex is present on web page?

Tags: python, regex, selenium

Is there a way in python to verify with `is_text_present()` method that certain regex is present on web page?

For example I made regex:

```
 p= re.compile('Today:\s\w')
```

and when using:

```
 try: self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present(p))
 except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
 time.sleep(10)
```

I get an exception.
Dont understand why?

```
sel = self.selenium
```

Comment: What if you will do it in general python.

Comment: You say `I get an exception`. What exception?

Comment: What about using `p.match('some text')` or `p.search('some text')`, if it returns something it means the pattern is present.

Comment: Yes, get_text() and re.search will hep

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/python/selenium.selenium-class.html) does not mention that the method would accept a compiled regex. Instead, you can pass a regex as a string prefixed with `rexeg:`. Try this:

```
p = r"regex:Today:\s\w"
```

Comment: The `r` marks a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), telling Python not to interpret the backslash as an escape character. In this case it does not make a difference, because `\s` and `\w` have no special meaning to Python, but it is a good habit to use a raw string when you want to include a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`assertRegex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegex) and [`assertNotRegex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertNotRegex) for that which test that a regex search matches.

Sample usage:

```
errors = "(?i)Example|MySQL|not a valid|error"
self.assertNotRegex(self.driver.page_source, errors)
```